# Changing the format of the number value with SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to do something using SQL, but I don't know if it can be done or how. I'm running a query using `sum()` and it returns a value like '145950.00'. But I want to return this value as '145.950,00'. Is there a way to do this with SQL or do I need to do it on the code side?

Comment: Will this be in MSSQL, MySQL or others?

Comment: I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 and above you can use below query to format numbers in your desired way. If you wan to truncate decimal points then use 'N0'. Here **2** indicates number of decimal points.

```
select format(145950.00, 'N2')
```

Comment: that's non-standard SQL. Please mention the DBMS product for which this works

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL, use this query:

```
SELECT FORMAT(145950.00, '#\.###\,\0\0')
```

This will give the specified result:

```
145.950,00
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked too but can you give a little more detail on how it works?

Comment: The result that you are requiring looks like a custom formatting. You've replaced the decimal separator with a comma (,) and the thousands separator with a period. This is the output that you need right?

Comment: Yes i do as you say. Thank you for your answer.